# How can i rewrite this part without using filter command

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

```
h=fir1(40,[50*Ts]);
z_t=filter(h,1,e_t);%ideal low pass filter
```

How can i rewrite this part without using  filter command

Answer (score 2):

You can do vector multiplication to do the multiply and adds. The only other tricky thing you need to do is pad the unfiltered data with about a filter's length of data at the beginning.  In my example, I created a 0.5 Hz sine wave with some noise on it that is filtered with a 1 Hz cutoff filter.

```
Wn = 0.2; % cutoff frequency (0.2 * 10/2 = 1 Hz)
N = 40; % FIR filter size
time = (0:199) / 10; % 10 Hz sample rate
% make a 0.5 Hz sine wave with noise
e_t = sin(2*pi*0.5*time) + 0.1 * randn(size(time));
h = fir1(N, Wn); 
N_act = length(h); % actual filter size
z_t = filter(h,1,e_t);

e_t_padded = [zeros(1, N_act - 1), e_t];
z_t_alt = zeros(size(z_t));
for idx = 1:(length(e_t_padded) - N)
   use = idx:(idx + N_act - 1);
   z_t_alt(idx) = h * e_t_padded(use)';
end
z_t_alt = z_t_alt(1:length(z_t)); % remove added points

plot(time, e_t, 'k')
line(time, z_t, 'color', 'b', 'linewidth', 3)
line(time, z_t_alt, 'color', 'r', 'linestyle', '-', 'marker', 'o')
legend('unfiltered', 'filtered with filter', 'alternate filter', 'location', 'southeast')
grid
```

Here is the resulting plot
[image]

Comment: Your example only works as your filter is symmetrical, however, if you use a arbitrary filter like `h=(0:N)/sum(0:N);` you will notice that your approach differs from matlabs `filter`function. You can overcome this by changing this line `z_t_alt(idx) = h * e_t_padded(use)';` to `z_t_alt(idx) = fliplr(h) * e_t_padded(use)';`